# Android Wear custom Notification

Tags: android, wear-os

When the custom notification is peeking on the homescreen, the system displays it with a standard template that it generates from the notification's semantic data. I have to swipe the notification up, to see the custom activity for the notification. I'm showing 'Swipe up to view' text as title for standard template.  My question is, Can i replace "Swipe up to view" with a time counter, which increase with timer?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String ns = getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
    callNotification(Html.fromHtml(getFormattedTime(CurrentPausedTime)),false,false);
    Thread notifyingThread = new Thread(null, updateTimerTaskCustom, "NotifyingServiceNew");
    notifyingThread.start();

}
private void callNotification(final Spanned spanned,boolean isPause,boolean pauseAction) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     displayIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomNotification.class);
     displayIntent.putExtra("exerciseTitle", "Running");
     displayIntent.putExtra("duration", CurrentPausedTime);
     displayIntent.putExtra("elepsedTime", 0);
     displayIntent.putExtra("isPause", isPause);

     displayPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
             0, displayIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


     Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ClearNotification.class);
     deletePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
             0, deleteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


     Intent pauseIntent = new Intent(ExerciseActionReciever.ACTION_PAUSE,
             null,getApplicationContext(), ExerciseActionReciever.class);
     pausePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
             0, pauseIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

     Intent stopIntent =new Intent(ExerciseActionReciever.ACTION_STOP,
             null,getApplicationContext(), ExerciseActionReciever.class);
     stopPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
             0, stopIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     Intent resumeIntent = new Intent(ExerciseActionReciever.ACTION_RESUME,
             null, getApplicationContext(), ExerciseActionReciever.class);
     resumePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, resumeIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

     NotificationCompat.WearableExtender wearableExtender =
                new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
                .setHintHideIcon(true)
                .setContentIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setDisplayIntent(displayPendingIntent);


         mNotifyBuilder =
                 new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
         .setContentTitle(""+spanned)
         .setDeleteIntent(deletePendingIntent)
         .extend(wearableExtender)
         .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Resume", resumePendingIntent)
         .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Stop", stopPendingIntent);

}

private Runnable updateTimerTaskCustom = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        timerHandlerCustom.removeCallbacks(updateTimerTaskCustom);
        timerHandlerCustom.postDelayed(updateTimerTaskCustom, 1000);
        if(!CustomNotification.isCustomCardAcrivityvisible )
        {
            CurrentPausedTime = CurrentPausedTime+1000;
            mNotifyBuilder.setContentTitle(""+Html.fromHtml(getFormattedTime(CurrentPausedTime)));
             mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICTIONTION_ID , mNotifyBuilder.build());          

        }

    }

};
```

Comment: Above code represents the activity from where i'm updating the notification.

Comment: You have posted some part of code (it has syntax errors by the way), but the question is swill the same (and it's answered in my answer already - I've also tested my asolution and it works as it should). If you have any problems of unwanted results please describe it somewhere. Also there is no place where you are switching the `isCustomCardAcrivityvisible` flag. Another thing: why are you using the `notifyingThread` `Thread` if you will replace it with a `timerHandlerCustom` `Handler` right after that...

Answer (score 1):

You can replace "Swipe up to view" with any text you want - like "53 sec". To update this value you will need to simply update your notification.

More information about updating notifications: http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html

BTW. If you want to optimise your code the note on top might be important to you:

> When you need to issue a notification multiple times for the same type
>   of event, you should avoid making a completely new notification.
>   Instead, you should consider updating a previous notification, either
>   by changing some of its values or by adding to it, or both.

**EDIT**: If you want, in addition, to use this solution with custom layout `Activity` you need to prevent notification from refreshing when this `Activity` is visible. Otherwise you will end up with `Activity` being created over and over again (blinking layout). Custom `Activity` in card layout is visible between the `onResume` and `onPause` events, so you need to detect that and update the whole notification ONLY when `Activity` is NOT visible to the user. The simpliest way is to use a static flag, but you can also play with other more advanced solutions (like `LocalBroadcastManager` etc.) to achieve this goal.

```
public class CustomLayoutActivity extends Activity {

    public static boolean isCustomCardAcrivityvisible;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout_activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        isCustomCardAcrivityvisible = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        isCustomCardAcrivityvisible = false;
    }
}
```

and if you're about to refresh your notification just do following check:

```
    if(!CustomLayoutActivity.isCustomCardAcrivityvisible) {
        updateNotification();
    }
```

---

**Alternatively** you can use `setUsesChronometer(boolean b)` method, to just display a timer (instead of `contextText`) that will be refreshed for you, but please notice that the timer will only be displayed (on Android Wear) if you will NOT set a custom layout to your card. So while this is not exactly what you want, you may consider this instead.

> Show the when field as a stopwatch. Instead of presenting when as a
>   timestamp, the notification will show an automatically updating
>   display of the minutes and seconds since when. Useful when showing an
>   elapsed time (like an ongoing phone call).

Comment: It's because the `Activity` inside your custom layout is being created again and again. I think there is no way to prevent it, but you can handle it yourself. If your `Activity` is visible (between `onResume` and `onPause`) you should just update the activity content instead of updating the whole notification, because the standard notification template is not visible anyway. If activity is paused you need to update the notification itself.

Comment: But onCreate,onPause and onResume all getting called everytime :-(

Comment: @user1672337 they are "all getting called everytime" only if you are updating your notification, right? My comments was about: If your activity is visible - there is no need to update whole notification. This resolves the problem of "blinking" activity. Update your notification ONLY when custom activity is NOT visible.

Comment: But how to check if the activity is visible??

Comment: In this case - if it's between `onResume` and `onPause`. You need to figure it our yourself - I can give you only an idea. The easiest way is to have some static variable like `isMyCustomActivityVisible` and trigger it to true/false in `onResume` and `onPause`. Play with it a bit and see what you can do with it:) If that flag is set to true - do not update your notitifation. Simple enough:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58273/discussion-between-user1672337-and-maciej-ciemiega).

Comment: @VipinVasu so... have you looked at my updated answer? Does it work for you?